# Child widgets of child widget not showing - why and how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I've encountered the problem, that I can not create a child widget of a child widget. I've tried using a class to create a window with widgets and alternatively a function to see if I don't understand something about how classes work, but the failure was the same.

I've boiled down the issue to the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('900x400')

frame1=tk.LabelFrame(root, text="frame1",width=800, height=400, bg='blue', bd=5).pack()
labelframe1=tk.LabelFrame(frame1, text="labelframe1",width=300, height=300, bg='green', bd=15).pack()
labelframe2=tk.LabelFrame(frame1, text="labelframe2",width=300, height=300, bg='yellow', bd=15).pack()

button1 = tk.Button(labelframe1,text="text").pack()
```

I don't get errors with this code, but the outcome is the same. Only the child of root is created, but not the children of the root child.

How can I create "grandchild" widgets?

Comment: Just by accident, I solved it. I formatted the pack() method into a separate line. It seems even though I found it in some half-hearted tutorials (which already contained other coding errors), the pack method doesn't seem to always work when attached to the end of the line with "somename = tk.Label(..."

Comment: Not that it doesn't work, it simply returns `None` and `None` as the parent will default to the root `Tk` instance. Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: This sounds too wide and too abstract for me personally to understand, but after reading another answer, I understood what you mean. So, technically you did answer, but I needed more input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, `x().y()` returns the value of `y()`. Thus, when you do `tk.LabelFrame(...).pack()` it returns `None`. Therefore, when you do `tk.Button(labelframe1, ...)` it's the same as `tk.Button(None, ...`, which causes the button to be a child of the root window.

Bottom line, it's a best practice to separate widget creation from widget layout. I also personally find that grouping layout code together makes the code much easier to understand. I think it's also a good practice to explicitly define which side the widget is being packed into.

```
frame1=tk.LabelFrame(root, text="frame1",width=800, height=400, bg='blue', bd=5))
labelframe1=tk.LabelFrame(frame1, text="labelframe1",width=300, height=300, bg='green', bd=15)
labelframe2=tk.LabelFrame(frame1, text="labelframe2",width=300, height=300, bg='yellow', bd=15)
button1 = tk.Button(labelframe1,text="text")

frame1.pack(side="top")
labelframe1.pack(side="top")
labelframe2.pack(side="top")
button1.pack(side="top").
button1 = tk.Button(labelframe1,text="text").pack()
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan! Thank you for the explanation as to the big why, because it almost had a flying-dutchman-quality to me that sometimes widgets show and sometimes they don't by placing the positioning method in the same line. And yes, I do find your formatting easy on the eye. I in turn find it easier to sort object-wise and not method-wise, but a method-wise formatting does look cleaner though.